# Как сделать, чтобы плагин интеграции WooCommerce с 1С не пересоздавал товары?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, 1с

Для Wordpress есть WooCommerce плагин для интеграции WooCommerce с 1C:Enterprise / 1С:Предприятие Data Exchange. И всё бы хорошо, но при синхронизации он каждый раз удаляет товары и создаёт новые, а мне надо чтобы старые товары оставались.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не так. Плагин не удаляет товары, если вы его специально об этом не попросите. Вы что-то делаете неправильно. У меня этот плагин ничего не удалял.

Смотрим код. Вызовы `wp_delete_post()` есть только в двух местах - в файле `clean.php` и в `offers.php`.

Файл `clean.php` может быть вызван только из функции `wc1c_template_redirect()`, и только в том случае, если url имеет вид `http://example.com/?wc1c=clean` или `http://example.com/wc1c/clean`, в полном соответствии с readme.txt.

В файле `offers.php` производится удаление только вариаций товара. В вопросе, правда, слово "вариации" отсутствует. Если вы хотите предотвратить удалений вариаций товара, то добавьте в wp-config.php строку

```
define( 'WC1C_PRESERVE_PRODUCT_VARIATIONS', true );
```

Comment: Это хорошо если всё так.

Comment: Это все именно так - я достаточно полазил по коду этого плагина.